# Angular Directives with Isolate Scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having a hard time understanding Angular Directives. I have a set of data from another file that I'm ng-repeating in my HTML (it's a bunch of country names and their flags). I need two directives, `<outer-box>` and `<flag>` inside that. On page load, the country names should appear with a placeholder image. When you click the placeholder image, the flag image should instead show, and the background color for  changes. **Both directives must be isolate scopes**. I'm getting stuck on how to change the styles/add a class of `<outerbox>` directive when you're within the `<flag>` directive.

**Here's my HTML**

```
<div class="blocks" ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <outer-box>
    </outer-box>
</div>
```

**and my angular code**

```
var app = angular.module('worldApp', []);

app.controller('mainController',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){
  $scope.countries = [];
  $http.get('./js/flags.js').then(function(response){
    $scope.countries = response.data;
  });
}]);

app.directive('outerBox', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: "<h1>{{country.name}}</h1>" + '<flag></flag>'
  }
});

app.directive("flag", function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'AE',
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       elem.bind('click', function() {
         elem.addClass("active");
         elem.css("background-image", 'url("{{country.flag}}")');
       });
       elem.bind('mouseover', function() {
           elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
       });
   }
  }

});
```

Comment: Would be easier if you made a jsfiddle example, or any other live coded one.

Comment: It is probably because your `flag` elements have no dimensions.